# How to get horizontal padding in Photoswipe?

Tags: photoswipe

I'm using photoswipe with disabled zoom, like suggested [here](https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/issues/846#issuecomment-121599761), but also want to avoid very landscapish images to reach beneath the prev/next arrows. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just found a solution, by

1) giving "padding" to the `.pswp__item`, like so:

```
.pswp__item {
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
}
```

2) updating the horizontal viewport size before resize:

```
pswp.listen('beforeResize', function(){
    pswp.viewportSize.x = pswp.viewportSize.x - 100;
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on @johjoh's answer, so I'm going to copy it here and **add the 3rd step required to get this working if you are using PhotoSwipe's `getThumbBoundsFn`**.

1) giving "padding" to the `.pswp__item`, like so:

```
.pswp__item {
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
}
```

2) updating the horizontal viewport size before resize:

```
pswp.listen('beforeResize', function(){
    pswp.viewportSize.x = pswp.viewportSize.x - 100;
);
```

3) Ensuring the `getThumbBoundsFn` properly calculates the `x` value by subtracting one side (50px in this example) from your calculated value:

```
bounds = {
    x: {x} - 50, 
    y: ..., 
    w: ..., 
}
```